# apache conf errordocument not working for declared 404 header in php

Tags: php, apache

I am issuing a `404` in my coupon.php page:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['cid'];
$rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($scx_dbh,"select * from locations where locid=$id"));
if($rs==NULL){
  header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
```

Inside my apache config `httpd.conf` I have the following declared:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

However when i **go to the page that issues the 404 it does not load the error document but just shows a browser error stating a 404.** It only seems to load when a page does not exist, not when i issue a 404 in `php`.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.4 or newer, you should really be using [`http_response_code(404);`](http://php.net/http-response-code) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a 404 error using `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` will only tell the end browser that there was an error finding this page. It won't show your custom error page.

If you want to show the end user an error page, you will need to include or redirect to it.

Place either of the two below options under your 404 header.

**Include Option**

`include('/path/to/404.html);`

**Redirect Option**

`header("Location: /path/to/404.html");`

Comment: I was informed that a redirect was not a good idea for SEO purposes.

Comment: A redirect is a terrible idea for lots of reasons (not least that it stops people looking at the URL and correcting a typo in it!). Include is fine.

Comment: It's a 404 error - there's no content there. So regardless of a negative impact on your SEO, you probably don't want that page or URL indexed anyway.

Comment: I think Im going to go with the inclusion seems much safer

Comment: @jkushner - It's my preferred option, but it's always good to know what other methods are available.

Comment: Thanks for the help @ajdi